# How to fix a possible IE11 bug that causes a new element to stay in `:hover` state?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, hover, internet-explorer-11

I have a button, each time it is clicked, a new button is created replacing the old one. When I click the edge of the button while quickly move off the button, sometimes the newly created button stays in `:hover` state in IE11. Whenever this happens, I have to hover over and off the button again to get rid of the hover state.

See my IE11 demo for details: https://recordit.co/4WJ3Xs71gg

To see it in IE11, please go to: https://cdpn.io/lzhoucs/debug/ExxbVzL/PBkNWnxZVvBM
To see the code, please go to: https://codepen.io/lzhoucs/pen/ExxbVzL

This is possibly is an IE11 bug since I can't reproduce it in any other modern browsers. My question is, is there a workaround/fix for this?

My IE11/OS version information:
[image]

Comment: I tried to test the issue on IE 11 (11.1.18362.0) version and it works fine without any issue. https://i.postimg.cc/zGrHHBjP/100.gif Is your IE browser is loaded with many tabs? it can makes it slower. If there is any updates available than install the latest one. Try to close other tabs and make a test with this code to check the performance. Let us know, which OS build you are using with IE 11 to make this test? It can be helpful for narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Deepak-MSFT, when you hover on the button, you have to click the button then quickly move off it, in which case a new button will be created. Merely hovering on the button won't cause the issue. Also the test page was the only tab in my IE11. I just updated my post with my OS/IE11 version.

Comment: for IE11, you can use jsbin https://jsbin.com/hiweharoma/1/edit?html,css,js,output  to share working online snippets , best is to make a snippet inside your question directly.   **i was unable to reproduce your bug from a fresh loaded IE11 and single tab (a genuine IE11)**

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin link @G-Cyr. I am definitely still able to reproduce it with the link you provided. Please see my demo on IE11: https://recordit.co/I01u7ob5nn. The hover issue happens in My 2nd, 4th and 11th clicks.

Comment: I again tested the issue with button click still It is working fine on my side. Did you try to check for updates? Is your IE is loaded with multiple tabs? It looks like your running with low memory caused this issue.